# postgres beginner: pgadmin4 object browser keeps disappearing randomly

Tags: pgadmin-4

For training purposes, I started to create my first postgres database with pgadmin-4 on a windows 10 parallels desktop.

During the first days, everything worked as expected. Today, I keep having problems while clicking on several objects in the object browser. Sometimes I click an object like constraints or schemas and all the objects in the browser suddenly disappear. After restarting pgadmin, it comes back again, but keeps disappearing after a while.

How do I explain and stop this behavior?

[image]